# How to make the task manager like in the windows to be smooth when moving the form around and when scrolling?

Tags: c#, winforms

When running the application, it's taking some seconds to load the list of processes and show it in the listview then when dragging the form around or trying to scroll up/down the whole application get stuck and freezing each time for a second or so.  it's not smooth like in the windows task manager.

what should I do to solve it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Process_List_App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DoubleBufferedListView customListView;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            customListView = new DoubleBufferedListView();
            InitializeListView(customListView);
            StartProcessListUpdater();
        }

        private void InitializeListView(DoubleBufferedListView listView)
        {
            // Add columns to the ListView
            listView.Columns.Add("Process Name", 200);
            listView.Columns.Add("PID", 80);
            listView.Columns.Add("Memory Usage (MB)", 120);

            // Set ListView properties
            listView.View = View.Details;
            listView.FullRowSelect = true;
            listView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            // Add the DoubleBufferedListView control to the form's controls
            Controls.Add(listView);
        }

        private void StartProcessListUpdater()
        {
            // Start the Timer to update the process list
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void UpdateProcessList()
        {
            // Get the list of running processes
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                // Find the ListViewItem corresponding to the process by its PID
                ListViewItem item = customListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubItems[1].Text == process.Id.ToString());

                if (item != null)
                {
                    // Update the memory usage column for the existing ListViewItem
                    item.SubItems[2].Text = (process.WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024)).ToString("N2"); // Memory usage in MB
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create a new ListViewItem for the process
                    item = new ListViewItem(process.ProcessName);
                    item.SubItems.Add(process.Id.ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add((process.WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024)).ToString("N2")); // Memory usage in MB

                    // Add the new item to the customListView
                    customListView.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the process list on each Timer tick
            UpdateProcessList();
        }
    }
}
```

and the class

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class DoubleBufferedListView : ListView
{
    public DoubleBufferedListView()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // WS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the form1 after adding changes and trying to use async Task but the problem still remains:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Process_List_App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DoubleBufferedListView customListView;
        private bool isScrollingOrMoving = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            customListView = new DoubleBufferedListView();
            InitializeListView(customListView);
            StartProcessListUpdater();
        }

        private void InitializeListView(DoubleBufferedListView listView)
        {
            // Add columns to the ListView
            listView.Columns.Add("Process Name", 200);
            listView.Columns.Add("PID", 80);
            listView.Columns.Add("Memory Usage (MB)", 120);

            // Set ListView properties
            listView.View = View.Details;
            listView.FullRowSelect = true;
            listView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            // Add the DoubleBufferedListView control to the form's controls
            Controls.Add(listView);

            // Subscribe to scroll and move events
            this.Scroll += Form1_Scroll;
            this.Move += Form1_Move;
        }

        private void StartProcessListUpdater()
        {
            // Start the Timer to update the process list
            timer1.Start();
        }

   private async Task UpdateProcessListAsync()
   {
             // Get the list of running processes asynchronously
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process process in processes)
        {
            // Check if scrolling or moving is in progress
            if (!isScrollingOrMoving)
            {
                ListViewItem item = null;

                // Access customListView.Items on the main UI thread using Invoke
                customListView.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    // Find the ListViewItem corresponding to the process by its PID
                    item = customListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubItems[1].Text == process.Id.ToString());
                }));

                if (item != null)
                {
                    // Update the memory usage column for the existing ListViewItem
                    customListView.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        item.SubItems[2].Text = (process.WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024)).ToString("N2"); // Memory usage in MB
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create a new ListViewItem for the process
                    item = new ListViewItem(process.ProcessName);
                    item.SubItems.Add(process.Id.ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add((process.WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024)).ToString("N2")); // Memory usage in MB

                    // Add the new item to the customListView on the UI thread
                    customListView.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        customListView.Items.Add(item);
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    });
   }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the process list on each Timer tick
            _ = UpdateProcessListAsync();
        }

        private void Form1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set scrolling flag to prevent updates during scrolling
            isScrollingOrMoving = true;

            // Delay to allow smooth scrolling
            Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                // Clear scrolling flag after delay
                isScrollingOrMoving = false;
            });
        }

        private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Set moving flag to prevent updates during form movement
            isScrollingOrMoving = true;

            // Delay to allow smooth form movement
            Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                // Clear moving flag after delay
                isScrollingOrMoving = false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove thie isScrollingOrMoving variable (and the Form1_Move and Form1_Scroll methods). They currently make your code syncronous again.

Comment: @PMF removed and still it's not smooth.

Comment: What's the frequency of your timer? Also, I think you should update each element with a single Invoke call, not multiple in a row. Invoke will execute that part on the UI thread, which can interfere with the window movement. So you should keep those calls as fast as possible and as rare as possible.